# Explanation of how charset affects storage/display

Tags: mysql, character-encoding

I find it infuriating that I don't understand this yet, but maybe some explanation will help.  This is a two part question, but hopefully both parts are small and directly related:

### Display

We recently had an issue where content was inserting `U+00a0` (non-breaking space) characters into a DB column with the `latin1` charset.  Simply doing `SELECT` prints out "Â" in the column.  I'm not sure if this is a product of selecting or of the display, but I believe it is the former.  `SELECT BINARY col` instead prints out " ", as well it should since my shell has `$LANG = en_US.utf8`.

A more visible example is "â„¢" vs. "™"

Using `SELECT CONVERT(col USING utf8)` still prints out "Â" and "â„¢" -- I wouldn't necessarily expect it to do differently, but where does the problem stem from?  Is it a problem that occurs at storage time?  Is there a way to get the UTF8 display out of the DB instead of relying on the UI to display it properly (if that makes sense?)

### Storage

In an attempt to reproduce this problem myself, I did the following:

```
CREATE TABLE chrs (
    lat varchar(255) charset latin1,
    utf varchar(255) charset utf8
);
INSERT INTO chrs VALUES ('™', '™');
INSERT INTO chrs VALUES (' ', ' '); -- U+00a0
```

However, this results in:

```
> SELECT * FROM chrs;
+------+------+
| lat  | utf  |
+------+------+
| ™    | ™    |
|      |      |
+------+------+
```

I would expect `lat` to display "Â" and "â„¢," so there is clearly something I do not understand.

What's more is this:

```
 > SELECT BINARY lat, BINARY utf FROM chrs;
+------------+------------+
| BINARY lat | BINARY utf |
+------------+------------+
| �           | ™          |
| �           |            |
+------------+------------+
```

This indicates that the values are being stored improperly (?) into `lat`.

I noticed that `SELECT @@character_set_client` was `utf8`, so I changed it to `latin1` and did the space insert again, but this yields

```
| Â    | Â    |
```

for *both* columns.  `SELECT BINARY lat` displays the space correctly, but `SELECT binary utf8` still prints out "Â."  I would expect the `utf8` column to work *more* correctly.

### To summarize:

- What does MySQL actually do to characters when you insert them?  Does it depend on the column charset, the client set, both, or something else?
- Is it possible to screw up data at insert time due to a mismatch of the above?  Or is it always possible to recover the originally inserted data?
- What does the `charset` on the column actually *do* with respect to storage/display?

Comment: Also worth looking at what `HEX(lat)` and `HEX(utf)` return.

Comment: Possibly relevant: The outputs of `status;`, `show create table chrs;`, and `show create database YOURDB;`.

Answer (score 3):

In short, your database seems to be OK, except when you explicitly tell it to behave strangely by changing [@@character_set_client] from [utf8] to [latin1]. Otherwise, I think you're seeing the effects of disagreements elsewhere between software components that use UTF-8 vs. Windows-1252.

How do we understand what's happening?

For a start, we recall that [in MySQL latin1 really means Windows-1252](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-we-sets.html), an encoding a little different from "Latin-1" proper which is also known as ISO/IEC 8859-1.

Now let's consider the following data concerning the trademark sign and the non-breaking space:

- Character: "trade mark sign"
- Unicode point: U+2122
- UTF-8 hexadecimal bytes: E2 84 A2
- Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) hexadecimal byte: there is no code for this character in this encoding
- Windows 1252 hexadecimal byte: 8D
- Character: "non-breaking space"
- Unicode point: U+00A0
- UTF-8 hexadecimal bytes: C2 A0
- Latin-1 (ISO 8859-1) hexadecimal byte: A0
- Windows 1252 hexadecimal byte: A0

Various ways that things go wrong:

- Characters resulting from interpreting trademark sign UTF-8 hexadecimal bytes as Windows 1252 bytes: â „ ¢

  - "latin small letter a with circumflex", "double low-9 quotation mark", "cent sign"
  - Note: Latin-1 and Unicode do not have a decoding at all for the hexadecimal byte 84 that Windows-1252 defines as "double low-9 quotation mark". Unicode encodes "double low-9 quotation mark" at a code point distant from there, U+201E.
- Characters resulting from interpreting non-breaking space UTF-8 hexadecimal bytes as Windows 1252 bytes: Â [non-breaking space]

  - "latin large letter a with circumflex", "non-breaking space"
- Characters resulting from interpreting trademark sign Windows-1252 hexadecimal byte as UTF-8 bytes: [no character: the platform's missing-character mark displays, usually a variation on a question-mark sign]

It appears that when you insert, your database stores the trademark sign in "latin1" as the hexadecimal byte 8D and in "UTF-8" as the hexadecimal bytes E2 A4 A2. It stores the non-breaking space in "latin1" as the hexadecimal byte "A0" and in UTF-8 as the hexadecimal bytes C2 A0. When you do a normal SELECT interactively, the "latin1" trademark sign is translated first into the Unicode point U+2122 and then into UTF-8 hexadecimal bytes E2 84 A2, which finally can be misinterpreted as if they were Windows-1252 bytes.

Where to find the data shown above about characters:

- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2122/index.htm
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_8859-1
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252
- [Windows-1252 correlation with Unicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305145.aspx)
- http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/201e/index.htm

Comment: Interesting information, but the terminal software is set with UTF-8 as the remote charset, which I would think would make the difference.  Also wouldn't it be displayed incorrectly at all times?  I can still get it to display correctly by selecting `BINARY`.  Another interesting fact I left out is that the "TM" is displayed correctly while the space is not for some clients.  This answer also does not explain the **Storage** behavior

Answer (score 1):

If every character hand-off in the chain is UTF8-aware, the character should be stored as 3 bytes in the UTF8 field, the hex of which is:

```
E284A2
```

And, in the latan1 field, as 1 byte, the hex of which is:

```
99
```

**However, your client and connection play a pivotal role in storing the character correctly and displaying it *as-stored*.**

Connecting with a `latin1` client over a `latin1` connection, I created and INSERTed both rows. Changed to utf8 client/connection and reinserted. The result is as follows:

Selecting from my latin1 connection:

```
mysql> select *, hex(lat), hex(utf) from chrs;
+------+------+----------+----------------+
| lat  | utf  | hex(lat) | hex(utf)       |
+------+------+----------+----------------+
| ™  | ™  | E284A2   | C3A2E2809EC2A2 |
|      |      | 20       | 20             |
| ?    | ?    | 99       | E284A2         |
|      |      | 20       | 20             |
+------+------+----------+----------------+
```

Selecting from my utf8 connection:

```
mysql> select *, hex(lat), hex(utf) from chrs;
+---------+---------+----------+----------------+
| lat     | utf     | hex(lat) | hex(utf)       |
+---------+---------+----------+----------------+
| â„¢     | â„¢     | E284A2   | C3A2E2809EC2A2 |
|         |         | 20       | 20             |
| ™       | ™       | 99       | E284A2         |
|         |         | 20       | 20             |
+---------+---------+----------+----------------+
```

The most confusing behavior here, in my opinion, is that `C3A2E2809EC2A2` somehow renders correctly when SELECTed from a latin1 client and connection. But, bearing in mind that the field is UTF8, MySQL is undoubtedly converting each set of 3 bytes into a corresponding latin1 byte for transmission, thus sending `E284A2` over the connection. And my terminal just so happens to interpret those three bytes as UTF8. (But, this is somewhat of a speculation. I'm not completely sure at which point the "inadvertently correct" conversion occurs here.)

And of course, MySQL kindly handles the latin `99` in a similar, but opposite manner.

Comment: Did you try inserting `U+00a0`?  Just curious.  It almost seems like the least confusing thing to do would be to make all columns binary and make the client in charge of the conversion.

Comment: @ExplosionPills Using the correct character encoding allows MySQL to properly sort and compare the field. For *most* character-type fields, matching needs to be done case insensitively -- not something that can be efficiently accomplished on a binary field. And in many cases, your users will expect to see sorting happen a particular way, which is not likely the same as the raw, binary sorting.

Comment: I thought sorting/comparison had to do with the collation and not the charset at all

Comment: @ExplosionPills That's also the primary reason it's good to use the *correct* character set. For most applications, regardless of what character set you *actually* use, you can get away with using latin1 fields over a latin1 connection. But, it goofs up your sorting. And if a client connect that actually *is* nice enough to tell the server it's a utf8 client, it'll see mush.

Comment: @ExplosionPills I haven't fully investigated it, but the binary collations don't have the same effects as the non-binary collations. (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-binary-collations.html)